# Equivalent condition to differentiability of a function in a general set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is an arbitrary set one said that $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable if for each point $x\in A$ exists an open set $U_x$ and a function $\tilde{f}:U_x \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\tilde{f}$ is differentiable and $\tilde{f}|_{A \cap U_x}=f|_{A \cap U_x}$. Is this equivalent to the existence of a single open set $A\subset U$ and a differentiable function $\tilde{f}:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\tilde{f}|_A=f|_A$?

I try to use partitions of unity but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straightforward with partitions of unity. The collection of sets $(U_x)$ for $x \in A$ is an open cover of $A$, so there exists a smooth partition of unity $(\rho_x)$ subordinate to this cover. Then $\tilde{f} = \sum_{x \in A} \tilde{f}_x \rho_x$ is smooth (where $\tilde{f}_x: U_x \to \mathbb{R}$ are the local extensions) and agrees with $f$ on $A$.