# Is the statement "$f$ is continuously differentiable over a closed set" mathematically incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For example, I am currently reading a sentence that writes:

"let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function over a closed and convex set $C$."

Sentence of this type appears everywhere in analyis, optimization, etc.

So let's imagine $f(x) = x^2$ over a closed set $C$ that is symmetric around $x = 0$.

Then we immediately have a problem in that $f(x) = x^2$ is not differentiable at the corners of $C$, hence $f$ could not have be continuously differentiable and this statement does not make sense.

Can someone check my reasoning?

Comment: $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ if it is continuous, has a derivative at each point of $(a,b)$, has left-hand derivative at $a$, right hand derivative at $b$ and the derivative thus defined is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Differentiabilty of $f$ on an arbitrary set $C$ is usually defined to mean the existence of a differentiable extension of $f$ on some open superset $U$ of $C$, such as for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460300/equivalent-condition-to-differentiability-of-a-function-in-a-general-set?rq=1 In most real-life practical cases your $f$ is actually already defined on some open set $U$ containing $C$ and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree that it is an "incorrect" statement, since it's mathematically imprecise. There are *multiple* (perfectly well-defined, but distinct) interpretations of what this phrase means. For instance, as pointed out in the comments, this could mean either (A) the existence of directional derivatives on the boundary of $C$, or (B) the existence of a differentiable extension of $f$ on an open superset of $C$.

Oftentimes in practice, when this appears in articles, one has to do a bit of guesswork. In some communities, one notion is more common/accepted than the other.